# Infragistics XamDataGrid ScrollingMode=DeferredWithToolTip property not working

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I have an app that uses a Infragistics XamDataGrid.  In the XamDataGrid properties I have

```
<igDP:XamDataGrid Name="dgData" 
    MouseDoubleClick="dgData_MouseDoubleClick"
    IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"  
    Background="White" 
    AutoFit="False"
    SelectedItemsChanged="dgData_SelectedItemsChanged"
    GroupByAreaLocation="AboveDataArea"
    BorderBrush="White"
    Grid.Row="1" ScrollingMode="DeferredWithScrollTips">
```

, and I have one of my fields set as

```
<igDP:Field Name="ReconName" Label="Recon" IsScrollTipField="True" IsPrimary="False"  >
```

This is an app that was built before I started working here and I am new to Infagistics.  On another page of the app the settings are as I have described above and the scrolling works as intended.  With this page however it seems to be stuck on ScrollingMode="Immediate" which is how it originally, but is causing this particular page to crash when the user scrolls through a large dataset.  So are there other areas of the app that I need to be looking to get the deferred scrolling mode to work correctly?  I have been to the Infragistics help page but all the post seem to point to just using this property and don't go into any other details.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is no difference in functionality from before to after you changed the ScrollingMode property, then perhaps the application isn't being rebuilt when you run.

Are you sure that the Configuration for your Solution is set up properly in the Configuration Manager?  Try changing the Configuration (or creating a new one) and ensure the 'Build' option is checked for all of the relevant projects.  Then go ahead and Clean and Rebuild the solution.

The Configuration Manager, Cleaning and Rebuilding options are all in the "BUILD" menu item in Visual Studio.

Comment: That was it.  The "Build" option in the config manager was not checked on my machine for this solution.  I set it and rebuilt as suggested and all was right with the world.  Thanks.